# Miniconda - Channel conda-forge not working - Traceback message

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, miniconda, conda-forge

I have installed Miniconda on my Windows 10 PC. I have followed the Data Science book by Wes McKinney.
I did everything 1:1 like this. I have then added conda-forge as a channel and also provided it with "strict".

```
(base) $ conda config --add channels conda-forge
(base) $ conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

I then executed `conda update conda` in the base environment and installed everything.
Then when I typed `conda list`, I got a weird message with "traceback" in "Anaconda Promt". Also other commands like `conda --version` did not work without such a message.
I searched for solutions but only found old amounts where either Conda was old or it was a bug from Conda. The only solution that worked for me was to reinstall Miniconda.
However, whenever I added conda-forge and did an update, it broke.

I also tried running `conda update --all`. Without success. I also updated everything via the default channel first and then added conda-forge. Did not work either. I also tried different sequences of this process. Without success.

Otherwise I haven't changed anything and this error only ever occurs when I add conda-forge as a channel.
The version I installed is the current one:
*Latest - Conda 23.3.1 Python 3.10.10 released April 24, 2023*
But as you know, I also updated it via Conda when I tried it. But there also came out this message.

Here's what I get out of it:

```
(base) C:\Users\Name>conda list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 16, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 70, in main_subshell
    p = generate_parser()
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 65, in generate_parser
    p = ArgumentParser(
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 152, in __init__
    self._subcommands = context.plugin_manager.get_hook_results("subcommands")
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 502, in plugin_manager
    from ..plugins.manager import get_plugin_manager
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .hookspec import hookimpl  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\hookspec.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .types import CondaSolver, CondaSubcommand, CondaVirtualPackage
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..core.solve import Solver
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .index import _supplement_index_with_system, get_reduced_index
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._request_methods import RequestMethods
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .response import BaseHTTPResponse
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 277, in <module>
    class BaseHTTPResponse(io.IOBase):
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 287, in BaseHTTPResponse
    DECODER_ERROR_CLASSES += (brotli.error,)
AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 129, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 376, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 19, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 75, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 88, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 159, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._request_methods import RequestMethods
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .response import BaseHTTPResponse
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 277, in <module>
    class BaseHTTPResponse(io.IOBase):
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 287, in BaseHTTPResponse
    DECODER_ERROR_CLASSES += (brotli.error,)
AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'

(base) C:\Users\Name>conda list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 16, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 70, in main_subshell
    p = generate_parser()
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 65, in generate_parser
    p = ArgumentParser(
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 152, in __init__
    self._subcommands = context.plugin_manager.get_hook_results("subcommands")
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 502, in plugin_manager
    from ..plugins.manager import get_plugin_manager
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .hookspec import hookimpl  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\hookspec.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .types import CondaSolver, CondaSubcommand, CondaVirtualPackage
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\plugins\types.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ..core.solve import Solver
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\solve.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .index import _supplement_index_with_system, get_reduced_index
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._request_methods import RequestMethods
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .response import BaseHTTPResponse
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 277, in <module>
    class BaseHTTPResponse(io.IOBase):
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 287, in BaseHTTPResponse
    DECODER_ERROR_CLASSES += (brotli.error,)
AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 129, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 376, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 19, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 75, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 88, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exception_handler.py", line 159, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 56, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 35, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import HTTPConnectionPool, HTTPSConnectionPool, connection_from_url
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ._request_methods import RequestMethods
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .response import BaseHTTPResponse
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 277, in <module>
    class BaseHTTPResponse(io.IOBase):
  File "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 287, in BaseHTTPResponse
    DECODER_ERROR_CLASSES += (brotli.error,)
AttributeError: module 'brotli' has no attribute 'error'

(base) C:\Users\Name>
```

The only solution that worked for me was to reinstall Miniconda.

Comment: Your question is a duplicate (for sure, I used the other to solve it). In any case: go to the file "C:\Users\Name\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py". Near the top there is an import of "brotli". After the exception handling (of such import) add brotli = None. Then continue to update and ev. install brotli. Then remove the line you added, and update again. Thinks now should work as normal

Comment: Thank you, but this is already there:

`try:
    try:
        import brotlicffi as brotli  # type: ignore[import]
    except ImportError:
        import brotli  # type: ignore[import]
except ImportError:
    brotli = None`

Comment: Copy the last line as a new line. As you see in the error, you have imported brotli, but urllib3 is expecting a newer version, so the errors. With the hack I describe, the module will ignore brotli (it is not essential to upgrade conda), and after you have a sucessful upgrade you can remove that line, and so using brotli (if needed)

Comment: Thank you, it helped.
Added the one new additional line with `brotli = None`.
Then saved the file. Ran `conda list` and it worked. However, there were no updates. I then also ran `conda update --all` and there were no updates there either. Then I deleted the line from the file "response.py" and saved it. After that it still worked without problems.

Comment: Because I do not find the duplicate question, and you have a fresher memory, feel free to self-answer to your question with all details. I think many people will have this problem in next few months.

Comment: No one should have to edit the files installed by Conda to get them to work. Please identify what channel these packages came from and file a bug report.

Comment: @merv: Yes, that's right. I have created 2 bug reports for this:  
https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io/issues/1966  
https://github.com/conda-forge/brotli-feedstock/issues/37  

Unfortunately, there has been no response yet.

Comment: @henry.23 thanks for filing that - I’ll try to take a look. If the book recommends prioritizing `conda-forge` channel, then it should simply recommend a Miniforge installation (I recommend Mambaforge), not Miniconda.

Comment: @merv I don't know why this is recommended. This is also the current way on his website. And the last edition of the book was also published only last year. And the author probably also works for "pandas", if I understood correctly.
But what is better about Mamba (e.g. Mambaforge) than Conda (e.g. Miniforge or Miniconda)?
I haven't really figured that out yet while searching.

Comment: Mamba is an alternative front-end to Conda - it does everything Conda does, just better, plus a little more. It *solved* the problem of slow solving so much so that recent Conda versions actually just use the Mamba implementation (so, not much performance difference nowadays in that respect). Currently the main advantage with Mamba is its **superior conflict reporting**. I also frequently use the `mamba repoquery` functionality to analyze package dependencies (forward and reverse).

Comment: @merv Thx! But unfortunately, they have closed the issue at conda-forge with the reference to a workarounds. I had the problem not with Conda or Miniconda, but only with conda-forge. https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io/issues/1966

Comment: @merv PS: I have now also tried Miniforge. However, I get the same problem when I do `conda update conda`. If I then enter `conda list`, the error comes again. Before trying Mambaforge, I wanted to know if it works with Miniforge without any problems.

Comment: @merv PPS: I have now deinsalled Miniforge and got Mambaforge with me. Do I understand correctly that `mamba` then takes over the job of `conda`? So I do all the commands now with `mamba xy`?
But how do I keep everything up to date? Is `mamba update mamba` sufficient? Because I did the latter and there were no problems with it. So `conda update conda` is no longer necessary and will be updated by `mamba update mamba` like all other standard packages?